# How to create SAS token to list\delete blobs

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-storage, azure-powershell

I tried creating SAS like this (**ADDING "Read" permission changes nothing**):

[image]

But it didnt work for me. I only want my script to get blob list, read metadata and delete old blobs.

> Get-AzureStorageContainer : The remote server returned an error: (403)
>   Forbidden. HTTP Status Code: 403 - HTTP Error Message: This request is
>   not authorized to perform this operation.

Also, I'd like to know whats the minimum possible permissions to achieve my goal.

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName xxx -SasToken zzz
$Containers = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $ctx
```

sample sas token:

```
?sv=2017-07-29&ss=b&srt=co&sp=dl&se=2018-03-31T21:24:06Z&st=2018-03-31T09:24:06Z&spr=https&sig=bWsg5sSPZF%2FaBXxfW6RoCH%2BlcFKBT6MFyMKTRM3I2jI%3D
```

Comment: This Cmdlet lists the containers in an account. For listing blobs, the cmdlet is Get-AzureStorageBlob. But nonetheless you shouldn’t get 403 error. Can you edit your question and include how are you calling this Cmdlet and how are you creating the storage context?

Comment: well, i'm not asking for that :) i'm asking: "how to create a proper sas token" @GauravMantri

Comment: Based on the screenshot (partial though), I believe you’ve selected the right permissions so your SAS token should be right. Please share your SAS token so that it can be checked for correctness.

Comment: is that documented anywhere? @GauravMantri

Comment: I’m actually looking for the value of SAS token you are using to create storage context.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I know why you’re getting this error. Let me provide an answer in a few minutes. But in the meantime if you use Get-AzureStorageBlob Cmdletusing this token, you should get this 403 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two things here:

1. **You're getting 403 error**: Assuming you're using the same SAS token as you have mentioned in the question along with [`Get-AzureStorageContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestoragecontainer?view=azurermps-5.6.0) Cmdlet, you will get this error. The reason for this is the purpose of this Cmdlet is to list blob containers in a storage account and for that you need to have `Service` permission in your SAS token (`srt` value in your SAS token should be `sco` instead of `co`). Because the required permission is not there in your SAS token, you are getting this 403 error. However if you use the same token along with [`Get-AzureStorageBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageblob?view=azurermps-5.6.0), you should not get any error.
2. **Necessary permissions for get blob list, read metadata and delete old blobs**: For this, you would need the following permissions:

   - Allowed Services: Blobs (b)
   - Allowed resource types: Container (c) and Object (o)
   - Allowed permissions: List (l), Read (r) and Delete (d)

With this combination you should be able to list blobs from a blob container using `Get-AzureStorageBlob`, read its metadata and delete the blobs.

**UPDATE**

So what I did was I followed your steps and tried to list the blob containers using `Get-AzureStorageContainer` Cmdlet. I also got the same error :).

Then I ran the Cmdlet with `Debug` and `Verbose` switches and found that for each blob container, this Cmdlet tries to get the [`ACL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-container-acl).

> _https://account.blob.core.windows.net/my-container?sv=2017-07-29&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=dl&se=2018-03-31T23:28:27Z&st=2018-03-31T15:2
>   8:27Z&spr=https&sig=signature&api-version=2017-04-17&**restype=container&comp=acl**.
>
> Confirm The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. HTTP
>   Status Code: 403 - HTTP Error Message: This request is not authorized
>   to perform this operation. [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command 
>   [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y Get-AzureStorageContainer :
>   The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. HTTP Status
>   Code: 403 - HTTP Error Message: This request is not authorized to
>   perform this operation. At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $ctx -Debug -Verbose
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureStorageContainer], StorageException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageCont
>   ainerCommand

Now the problem is that you can't fetch ACL for a container using a shared access signature, you would need to use the account key (same thing goes for creating a shared access signature). This is the reason you're getting 403 error back from the service.

Not sure you would classify this as a bug in `Get-AzureStorageContainer` or would want to put in a feature request allowing you to list blob containers without getting its ACL but they way things are today, you can't list blob containers using this Cmdlet and a SAS token.

Comment: but the `service` thing is checked? I've created another SAS with `sco` and still getting the same error

Comment: why am I so freaking lucky

Comment: :D. But if you know the blob container, then you can use the other cmdlet to list and delete the blobs.

Comment: Other way would be to invoke list blob containers REST API using Invoke-WebRequest.

Comment: yeah, thats pretty obvious, but i was unable to find examples online and when I saw an article on msdn to create required parameters I kinda went `sad panda`. I'd rather use connection string, tbh. much easier. thanks though!